# Temporarily disable change-events NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios

After I insert a new entity in Core Data, some attributes are being changed. After changing one attribute a change-event is already sent to the NSFetchedResultsController-delegate.

Is it possible to change multiple attributes after each other and only when the latest attribute is changed, an event is sent to the NSFetchedResultsController-delegate that the object is modified.